# Trouble with adding Trusted Provider (SAML 2.0): can not parse my service provider metadata

Tags: saml-2.0

I'm getting error message in Novell iManager "*The XML is malformed. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'md:EncryptionMethod'. One of '{"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":KeyInfo}' is expected.*" when add this service provider metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://.../" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAssertionsSigned="true" AuthnRequestsSigned="true"> 
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption"> 
        <md:EncryptionMethod xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/> 
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
          <X509Data><X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate></X509Data>
       </KeyInfo> 
      </md:KeyDescriptor> 
      <md:AssertionConsumerService isDefault="true" index="0" Location="https://.." Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
  </md:SPSSODescriptor> 
  <md:Organization>...</md:Organization> 
   ...
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

What I do in Novell iManager: IdentityServers -> AH DMZ Identity Server -> New Trusted Provider -> Service Provider -> Source: Metadata Text

The strange thing is that it complains on lack of **KeyInfo** element while it's here with the correct namespace. Any idea why it might be?

If I specify third-party metadata from here: https://federation.njedge.net/metadata/njedge-fed-metadata.xml it says

"*The XML is malformed.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Organization'. One of '{"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":Signature, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":Extensions, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":RoleDescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":IDPSSODescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":SPSSODescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":AuthnAuthorityDescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":AttributeAuthorityDescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":PDPDescriptor, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata":AffiliationDescriptor}' is expected.* 
"

Looks like it expects some service provider specific metadata file format, and unfortunately I was unable to find any information about different formats of SAML 2.0 metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loos like there were 2 issues: 
1) Novell expects strict order of elements 
2) It does not recognize default namespace like `<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">` instead use `<somenamespace:KeyInfo xmlns:somenamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">`

weird :)

Comment: Are you doing this in java? I am implementing similar solution where i need to parse SP metadata in my application to extract the details like signing cert, assertion endpoint, etc. Are you aware of any standard java library to achieve this?